# NSDateComponentsFormatter for not correctly translating German?

Tags: ios, localization, nsdatecomponentsformatter

```
NSDateComponentsFormatter *formatter;
formatter = [[NSDateComponentsFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.unitsStyle = NSDateComponentsFormatterUnitsStyleShort;
formatter.allowedUnits = NSCalendarUnitDay;
NSString *string = [formatter stringFromTimeInterval:seconds];
```

This is returning `2 d` for German, while I would expect `2 t`? If the style is changed `NSDateComponentsFormatterUnitsStyleFull` then I see `2 Tage`

I also tried French and Russian to compare. Seeing correct short letters, ie. `2 j` and `2 д` respectively

Any German developers can shed light on this? Is this a known bug? Using iOS 9.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`d` is the correct German abbreviation. It refers to the Latin word "dies" (meaning "day").

Comment: Interesting. Would the same apply to hours? I'm seeing "8h" instead of "8 Std" (Stunden). Just want to confirm this is what people in Germany are used to seeing in their apps?

Comment: Yes, "h" is used for hour (again from Latin, "hora").